# How do I change from ascending to descending in MergeSort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I can properly run my code to sort an array to in ascending order, but when I try to do descending I keep getting index out of range. I've been trying to debug it and run through my for loops to figure out the problem, but I'm getting no where. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

```
def merge_sort(arr, beg, end):
    if beg < end:
        mid = (beg +  end) // 2
        merge_sort(arr, beg, mid)
        merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, end)
        merge(arr, beg, mid, end)

def merge(A, beg, mid, end):
    n1 = mid - beg + 1
    n2 = end - mid

    L = [0] * (n1 + 1)
    R = [0] * (n2 + 1)

    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = A[beg + i]

    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = A[mid + 1 + j]

    L[n1] = float('inf') 
    R[n2] = float('inf') 

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(beg, end + 1):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1

    return A

myList = [26,54,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
merge_sort(myList, 0, len(myList) - 1)
print(myList)
```

My output for this MergeSort is: [17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77,93]
which is in ascending order, I want my output to be the opposite:
[93, 77, 55, 54, 44, 31, 26, 20, 17]

For these lines of code:

```
for k in range(beg, end + 1):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
```

I did switch out the <= with > but I get index range errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For descending, the sentinel values need to be max negative values:

```
    L[n1] = -float('inf')            
    R[n2] = -float('inf')
```

For stability (maintain original order for equal values):

```
            if L[i] >= R[j]:
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain to me why the sentinel values need to be negative? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Jasmine - The sentinel values are being used to prevent scanning beyond the bounds of the arrays. At some point during the merge, a sentinel value is reached in one of the sub-arrays L or R, after which the remaining elements from the other sub-array are copied to A. For descending merge, the sentinel values need to be max negative values, otherwise, the inner loop would copy the sentinel value and increment the index, going past the end of L or R.